# Average speed based on time and distance - Python

Tags: python-3.x, time, distance

I'm tryng to figure out how I can fix my problem here, but it keeps failing.

So I currently have this code:

```
@staticmethod
def avg_speed():
    # Speed = Distance ÷ Time
    cur_time = datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
    db_time_record = DB().start_time()
    time_diff = cur_time - db_time_record
    # print(str(time_diff).split(":"))
    total_distance = DB().get_total_distance()
    result = (total_distance / (float(time_diff.total_seconds()))) * 60
    return round(result, 2)
```

But the thing is, the average speed is so high, it is not possible that the speed is correct.... Now, what the `DB()` record has a `MySQL DATETIME object`.

That looks like: `datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")` (`2017-08-22 15:28:19`)

Now what I want, as stated in the code, is the average speed based on the distance traveled and the time. The distance is in meters and the time should be in seconds?

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a MySQL database available to test your code, but if you can read the start_time from the DB as a string in the format like "2017-08-22 15:28:19" then the following example shows how to do a speed calculation:

```
import datetime

# (simulate reading time from database as string)
time_string_from_db = "2017-08-22 15:28:19"

dbtime              = datetime.datetime.strptime(time_string_from_db, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
cur_time            = datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)

print ("dbtime:      " + repr(dbtime))
print ("cur_time:    " + repr(cur_time))

elapsed = cur_time - dbtime
seconds = elapsed.total_seconds()

print ("elapsed:     " + repr(elapsed))
print ("seconds:     " + repr(seconds))

distance = 500
speed = distance / seconds

print ("speed:       " + repr(speed))
```

Hope some of this may be useful.

Comment: I'll test it as soon as I can :)